# Subir laravel en un WMC/Cpanel pero con estructura public_html/wmc/public

Tags: laravel-5, cpanel

Tengo entendido que para despleglar una app de laravel, necesitas meter tu carpeta public en `public_html` pero como accedo a ella?

en mi raiz esta de la siguiente manera

```
/
./key <---proyecto de laravel
./public_html
../wmc/public <--- carpeta public de laravel
```

Pero cuando intento acceder a ella me da error de servidor que no pudo resolver la petición, este es mi index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../key/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../key/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

en `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        // app()->bind('path.public', function() {
        //     return base_path().'/../public_html';
        // });
        App::bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/public_html';
        });
    }
```

Pero aun asi no se que puede estar pasando, mas sin encambio meto todo a public_html y apunto a key/public, obvio funciona pero como puedo evitar hacer esto

Comment: El proyecto Laravel iría en el directorio que contiene a `/public_html`, sería como si a tu proyecto le cambias el nombre del directorio `/public` a `/public_html`.

Comment: Es lo que hice en el appserviceprovider pero aún así falla

Comment: En AppServiceProvider le está indicando a Laravel que use el directorio `/public_html` en vez de `/public`. No llego a entender lo que pusiste de tu estructura de directorios del host, pero si tu directorio raíz es `/` y ahí se encuentra `/public_html`, debes subir tu proyecto al directorio raíz, y mover el contenido de `/public` a `/public_html`.

Comment: entonces si mi carpeta public de laravel esta en: wmc/public, tengo que apuntar hacia ella?

Comment: No, tienes que apuntar el server a `/public_html`, el directorio `/public` ya no existirá.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces ahora ya está apuntando con base_path.’/public_html’

Comment: Creo que no nos estamos entendiendo. Te comento lo que creo que funcionaría por pasos. **1.** Subes el contenido del directorio donde está tu proyecto al directorio raíz `/` del servidor (que ya contenía un directorio `/public_html`). Van a quedar `/public` y `/public_html` en el mismo nivel. **2.** Mueves el contenido de `/public` a `public_html` (ya no quedará nada en `/public`). **3.** Configuras `AppServiceProvider` para que Laravel sepa que debe usar `/public_html` en lugar de `/public`. **4.** Apuntas tu servidor a `/public_html`.

Comment: Perfecto lo entiendo, pero dado que en ester servidor hay varios proyectos (de otro tipo) necesito subir este contenido a una carpeta por ejemplo "key" y que laravel apunte a esta carpeta?

Comment: Bueno, no entiendo yo entonces. Si puedes apuntar el servidor a cualquier directorio, no necesitas cambiar nada en laravel. Sube tu proyecto tal cual lo tienes en local y apunta el server a la carpeta public.